# How can I make a class variable unique

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a sample code:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal

class MyClass:
    pass

class PSClass(QObject):
    onRequest = Signal(str)
    onMySignal = MyClass()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.onRequest.connect(self.printSomething)

    def send(self, message:str):
        self.onRequest.emit(message)

    def printSomething(self, data:str):
        print(data)

sample_01 = PSClass()
sample_02 = PSClass()

sample_01.send(f"Signal ID:{id(sample_01.onRequest)}, MyClass ID:{id(sample_01.onMySignal)}")
sample_02.send(f"Signal ID:{id(sample_02.onRequest)}, MyClass ID:{id(sample_02.onMySignal)}")

>>> Signal ID:56331376, MyClass ID:15825232
>>> Signal ID:56331392, MyClass ID:15825232
```

I don't understand why **Signal** ID is unique but not **MyClass**, cause I defined both of them at the start of the class.

How can I make **MyClass** behave like **Signal**?

Comment: I don't know QT very well, but I'd guess that their `Signal` class is some kind of descriptor. I'd be curious if you *ever* get the same "Signal ID". You may be getting a different object every time, even when you check the same instance of your `PSCLass`.

Comment: @trincot: No, `MyClass` definitely doesn't implement the descriptor protocol. The process of accessing `someinstance.onRequest` here produces new objects each time via the descriptor protocol, the same way doing `someinstance.send` produces a new bound method each time.

Comment: Yeah, every time I create a new PSClass, the onRequest ID is different and unique to the created variable, and I want to replicate the same behaviour for MyClass. that is unique every time PSClass is created.

Comment: @Bear: Blckknght's suggestion was that the `onRequest` ID is likely different even when accessed on the *same* instance, not just on a different instance. Try doing this: `sample = PSClass()`, `sig1 = sample.onRequest`, `sig2 = sample.onRequest`, `print(id(sig1), id(sig2))`. While a descriptor *could* return the same thing for the same instance each time via some sort of caching (e.g. by a lazily set attribute on the instance itself), it's more common to find them producing a new value each time. I assigned them to variables to ensure memory wasn't reused for both accesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Signal` almost certainly implements [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and uses it to produce new objects bound to the instance it was accessed on when you access `.onRequest`.

This is not the normal behavior for typical class attributes (aside from methods, which are normal Python functions, which happen to implement the descriptor protocol to enable them to work the same way), and your `MyClass` clearly doesn't implement the descriptor protocol, so it won't do work like that for you.

For anything that doesn't perform this work for you, and must be unique per instance, define it on the instance, not as a class attribute, e.g. (omitting all irrelevant code before and after), changing the beginning of your class definition to:

```
class PSClass(QObject):
    onRequest = Signal(str)
    # onMySignal no longer a class attribute, it *shouldn't* be shared among all instances

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.onMySignal = MyClass()  # It's now created uniquely on initializing each new instance
        self.onRequest.connect(self.printSomething)
```

Yes, you *could* implement the descriptor protocol to achieve a similar effect, but:

1. There's no benefit to doing so most of the time
2. It's a lot more work than you're typically going to want to do, especially if the binding process should produce the *same* object each time, rather than recreating it on each access (the way Python methods do, in theory, and the way `Signal` likely does it).
3. It's unPythonic when the binding process is supposed to produce the same object when accessed on the same instance. Attributes intended to differ by instance *should* be set in `__init__`, not assigned as class attributes (which implies they're shared between all instances and/or meaningful without an instance being involved at all, e.g. `PSClass.onMySignal` should be equally as valid as `sample_01.onMySignal`).

Comment: hmm.. interesting; thank you for the solution. I didn't know about "descriptor protocol". Let me have a look at it and understand how it is designed.

Comment: @Bear: To be clear, you don't know about it, but it underpins literally every method call you make in Python. Modern Python has some special optimizations that avoid actually producing the bound method object in many cases, but if you aren't calling the method immediately, it does the same thing `Signal` is doing (and it definitely doesn't cache, so the ID can change from access to access), e.g.  `send1 = sample_01.send`, `send2 = sample_02.send`, `print(id(send1), id(send2))` will report different IDs for two copies of the *same* function bound as a method to the *same* instance.

Comment: It's also how `@property` is implemented, `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod`, etc. It's just a very finicky/complex beast, and it's rarely something you want to do except in special cases; in this case, for `MyClass`, I'm 99.9% certain you want instance attributes, not class attributes that produce new instances via the descriptor protocol.

Comment: Yes, that is the topic that I was looking for hours; yeah, I do need the variable to be unique for every class created and handle everything within itself. Thank you for pointing it out.